# start up failure after some kind of update

Tags: boot

have a laptop with a ubuntu 20+ version. i think.
actually left it aside for a while since i didnt have time to "deal" with it cause of really weird work hours. managed to find it again and restart my ....lessons. first thing thing i noticed is the updates. just 60 - 70 kb in size didnt make sense.
i found out that my version of ubuntu lts i think ended in july 22. however before i was notified of a new version to download but now i cant. updates said that there in no secure way to download X updates and so they are disabled. i can only perform a fresh install.
anyways i pressed ok and after that it crashed to a blank screen... i only managed to see something {FAILED} in the background. now, it will power up show me decrypt page and then nothing...... the screen is on with a blinking cursor...

Comment: if your version of Ubuntu "*ended in july 22*" then it's time to install a fresh, supported release anyway. we don't answer questions or help troubleshoot versions past their end date (that's what the end date means). the release ending in july 22 was ubuntu 21.10, which was not lts.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (the 2020-October release) has ended support; refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ so is that what you meant.  The *release-upgrade* process for that ended when [Ubuntu 21.04 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HirsuteUpgrades

Comment: i remember seeing the tiger background at a point so i must be this one. by smashing shift though i get the option of recovery with linux 5.13.0.19 and 5.13.0.20......however, none get me to a working enviroment. so the order would be to get the old intallation up again to take off my files from the disk and after install again.

Comment: The 5.13 kernel was used by Ubuntu 21.10 which is EOL & thus off-topic here, however it's upgrade path was to 22.04 thus will be easier. In your case; I'd boot *live* media (such as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) and perform your backups (*copy wanted files to other media*) using that environment, then re-install a supported system. Ubuntu Desktop (& *flavors*) can be re-install non-destructively meaning no loss of files/configs & even have your *manually installed* packages (if from Ubuntu repositories) re-installed automatically.. But your specifics are unknown (20+ isn't a valid system)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: been playing around with a bunch of stuff..... a) yes, i can get grub. b) two versions aka two recovery modes. i get a welcome to ubuntu 20.10 message. c) apparently there is no space. i get the message that we need, additional space etc etc. also d) as not to totally piss off people who say that this is off topic, i downloaded a iso and using rufus made it into a usb. got the out of range error, got past it.... i boot to an installation. no option for a live. i didnt go through as i want the files before formating to upgrade

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades